# How do you remove the data value from the mouse-over result in radar chart?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Currently I am working with a dynamic set of data and Chart.js. There is no standardised scale within the data I am using, so I have created a simple algorithm, for example:

```
3 out of 7 for question 1 [3 * (12 / 7)]
2 out of 9 for question 2 [2 * (12 / 9)]
6 out of 7 for question 3 [6 * (12 / 7)]
So that all the results for the Radar Graph are measured equally at 12.
```

By doing this the value is not going to be correct, even though the position of the point in respect to the rest of the graph will be.

```
[Label]Question 1 (3/7) : [Value]5.14
```

I have already included the true value in the label by combining the label with the data in the label array.

So I would like to show just the label when the mouse hovers over the spoke or dot on the chart.

```
Question 1 (3/7)
```

Is there a way of doing this without messing around with the Chart.js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `tooltipTemplate` option

```
new Chart(ctx).Radar(data, {
    tooltipTemplate: "<%=label%>",
});
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/dz6mt4dy/

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you.  I had checked on the Chart.js documentation, but couldn't see this. Really appreciate your help on this.